# javac.getStandardFileManager return null

Tags: java, web-applications

I make my own web server, that compile user scripts from folder.
It works perfectly on Netbeans Ide, but then I compile my project, and run it from the jar I have an error:

```
Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at webserver.compiler.Compiler.<init>(Compiler.java:35)

Compiler.java :
private final JavaCompiler javac = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
private final StandardJavaFileManager standartFileManager =
      javac.getStandardFileManager(diacol, null, null);
```

I suppose, that something wrong this classpath. %)

Comment: @giko: Welcome to StackOverflow! I reformatted your code (select and press Ctrl+K in editor).

Comment: Where are all of these classes from? I don't recognise the names.

Answer (score 0):

Likely your system is pointing to the java.exe from your jre.  You'll need to use the java.exe from your jdk since jre doesn't have the compiler.